# Java unit tests, directory layout

Tags: java, unit-testing

When building a suite of unit tests for Java code, is there a convention for where to place test code in relation to source code?

For example, if I have a directory `/java` that contains a bunch of `.java` source files, is it better to put the test cases in `/java` itself or use something like `/java/test`.

If the latter is preferred, how do you test the internals of the code when the `private`  /`protected` members of a class aren't available outside the package?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can put the tests in the same package as the original classes, even if the source code is under its own directory root:

```
PROJECT_ROOT
    +--- src/
    +----test/
```

You can declare a class `com.foo.MyClass` under `src` and its test `com.foo.MyClassTest` under `test`.

As for access to private members, you can use **reflection** to invoke the methods (altering their accessibility via `Class.getDeclaredMethod.setAccessible`), or you could use something like testng/junit5 to put some annotation-driven tests on the source code itself (I personally think this is a bad idea).

Why not check out some projects on `java.net` to see how they've organized things, for example [**swinglabs**](https://swinglabs.dev.java.net/source/browse/swinglabs/trunk/) (the SVN repository is pretty slow I'm afraid)?

Answer (score 130):

I recommend following the [Apache Software Foundation's standard directory structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), which yields this:

```
module/
  src/
    main/
      java/
    test/
      java/
```

This keeps tests separate from source, but at the same level in the directory structure. If you read through how Apache defines their structure, you'll see it helps partition other concerns out as well, including resources, config files, other languages, etc.

This structure also allows unit tests to test package and protected level methods of the units under test, assuming you place your test cases in the same package as what they test. Regarding testing private methods - I would not bother. Something else, either public, package, or protected calls them and you should be able to get full test coverage testing those things.

By the way, the link above is to Maven, Apache's standard build tool. Every Java project they have conforms to this standard, as well as every project I have encountered that is built with Maven.

Comment: +1 Even if you don't use maven, it's a good idea to follow this layout (a kind of de facto standard based on industry best-practices).

Comment: The only reason Maven is mentioned here is because its website is one place where the Apache standard directory layout is documented. Your like or dislike of it is irrelevant with regard to whether the directory structure in question is a good one. Perhaps you can comment on an answer that aligns with your opinion to indicate why that directory structure is superior.

Comment: I would not like to follow this recommendation because you cannot just export the "src" foulder to a jar/war. You have to explicitly exclude the test package and would rebuild the whole package structure under the test package.

Comment: If you are coding in pure Java, the `java` directory is an unnecessary addition

Comment: Well, it should be mentioned that usually both the `main` and `test` folders have a `resources` source folder that compiles into the same output folder the `java` folder does, allowing easy separation of Java code and resource files at the source level. I also like this structure because it keeps the top level free of multiple source folders... it's a very logical organization. And yes, this has nothing to do with whether or not one likes Maven.

Comment: What about the output? a `target/classes` and `target/test-classes` folder perhaps?

Comment: Yes. That is where Maven places the output, which makes sense to me regardless of the build tool: a single directory to place output in (easily deleted) with different kinds of output in sub-directories.

Comment: This is Gradle's default layout as well.

Comment: @duffymo What do you use instead of Maven? Thanks.

Comment: I made that comment eight years ago.  I've since grown to understand and love Maven.  I won't work without it now.  People can change.

Comment: @duffymo Thanks for your reply ;)

Comment: @SingleShot, let say I use `src/main/com/mycompany/...` & `src/test/com/mycompany/...` structures, should I rename the package from `com.mycompany` to `main.com.mycompany` and `test.com.mycompany` respectively?

Answer (score 11):

Most of the times is done like this:

```
<SOME_DIR>/project/src/com/foo/Application.java
<SOME_DIR>/project/test/com/foo/ApplicationTest.java
```

So, you keep them separated and you can still test the package/protected functionality because the test is in the same package.

You can't test private stuff, unless it is declared inside the class it self.

Upon delivery, you just pack the `.class` generated by src, not the tests

Comment: test should be in the src folder. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 7):

Actually it makes a lot of sense to separate your Production and Test projects into 2 separate entities, but have the same package structure in both projects.

So if I have a project 'my-project' I also create 'my-project-test', so I have the following directory structure:

```
my-project
  +--- src/com/foo
my-project-test
  +---test/com/foo
```

This approach ensures that test code dependencies do not pollute production code.

In my personal opinion, package private and protected methods should be tested as well as public methods.  Hence I want my test classes in the same package as production classes.

Answer (score 2):

This is how we have it set up and we like it.

```
build/
src/
test/build/
test/src/
```

All testing code compiles into its own build directory. This is because we don't want production to contain test classes by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a **Java library** module in [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/index.html) it creates a default class under:

```
[module]
   + src/main/java/[com/foo/bar]
```

If you look into `[module].iml` file, you will find that path as well as the path for tests, that you can utilize. The below is a summary:

```
<module>
  <component>
    <content>
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
    </content>
  </component>
</module>
```

What you can do in particular is to create a directory for tests to have the following structure:

```
[module]
   + src/main/java/[com/foo/bar]
   + src/test/java/[com/foo/bar]
```

The above structure will be recognized by [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/index.html) and your files underneath will be included into the module.

I assume that that structure is a recommended layout for code and tests.