# Managing test cases, existing in a single file

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have a lot of test cases written in a single file. They are actually sort of instructions, which can be read and run from inside JAVA.

The problem is this approach is not good. The file becomes big and unmanageable with a lot of test cases. How should I manage them? I was thinking of splitting them in different files, and having a XML Database for metadata. Any better ways?

P.S: They are not plain English test cases, they are sort of instructions which can be run inside JAVA.

Update: But they are not unit tests, more of like functional tests and they are not test classes. A program reads the different test cases from file and runs them.

Comment: On of the best practise is to have one file per classes tested as described here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540324/java-unit-tests-directory-layout

Comment: But they are not unit tests, more of like functional tests and they are not test classes. A program reads the different test cases from file and runs them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the approach that is used by Cucumber.  Here you find human readable "feature" descriptions that each contain a number of different scenarios for that feature to test it out completely.  No one feature file is a single test, none are test classes themselves, and a program reads all the feature files and runs them.

The overall pattern here would probably be instructive for you as well.

http://cukes.info/

Note that recently there has been a significant amount of work done making writing these cuke tests in Java easy as well as the original native language of Ruby.

The Java port of Cucumber uses a JUnit 4 custom test runner like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Feature("create_user_account.feature")
public class CreateUserAccountTest {
}
```

You can run this class as a JUnit test and the console output looks very similar to what you see on the Cucumber website.  So you basically have one of these "test classes" for every feature.  Then you can run a whole package worth of features, a single feature, or the entire project worth of features all at once by either grouping them into test suites or using Eclipse's test run batching.

Comment: that is very similar to what I'm doing, but without Cucumber. Do you know how they manage different scenario(or feature description) files?

Comment: I'll add more to my answer so you can see it a little more clearly...  Again, not suggesting that you have to use Cucumber, but the approach they use is similar to what you describe and well thought out I think.