# How to organize unit and integration tests?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing

I have an eclipse (not maven) project in which I organize the code in two source folders: src and test.
The hierarchy of test folder is parallel to src to make it easy to find classes and stay organized.
Now, I was talking about my unit tests. I'd like to separate unit tests from my integration tests as well, but I'm not sure what would be the best way of doing so.
Maybe I should have another source folder just for my integration tests? Or maybe it should be under a separate package in test source folder?
I will be happy to hear how you do it, thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540324/java-unit-tests-directory-layout

Comment: This question may get closed for being too broad. Remember from the alert on the right side of the screen when you made this question - "*We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.*"

Comment: I don't think that your question is low quality though. To make this question and other questions like it more answerable, include details about how you have chosen to do this task in the past, and if possible, talk about other methods you could imagine doing this. Then you can ask which one of these methods is the best, or most logical, or which one follows convention the closest. Now your question is **definitely** answerable. Even ff you haven't listed the most preferred or correct way to complete the task, someone will surely talk about it and discuss it and your methods as well. Cheers!

Comment: If you are not constrained by a tool you are using, this is a matter of personal preference rather than objective fact.

Answer (score 2):

Personnal opinion (because that's all about personnal preferences here) is : separate packages for different test level

```
src/ //source folder
...
test/ // source folder
    test/ //packages
        integration/
        unit/
    tools/
```

I personally stopped maintaining the source package hierarchy for test classes since I found it very costly when you refactor your sources.

I also use the JUnit Categories to clearly separate test level in a visible way.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is good: another source folder is probably the best option. Usually people name it something like: `it`, `test-integration`, `test-it`, `integrationtest`.

If you are using Maven as a build tool, this can be achieved by `build-helper-maven-plugin`. If not, just add manually in your IDE another source folder.